# WARNING: [XmlResourcesTransformer] No mapping for: android/support/FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS

Tags: android, gradle, androidx, fileprovider

On gradle sync, it errors with:

```
WARNING: [XmlResourcesTransformer] No mapping for: android/support/FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS
```

```xml
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
 android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
 android:exported="false"
 android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I have added the relevant code, `        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>`

Comment: Please add your "relevant" code in the question, not as a comment :)

Comment: What's in `provider_paths` xml file?

Comment: @deadfish Added to the question

Comment: @ 于永志 : since this tool related question , please add version information (gradle, android ..) that may help to narrow down an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Likely this comes from Jetifier - and disabling it (while feasible) might work around the issue, as there won't be any attempts at mapping it. While `android:exported="false"` probably doesn't make much sense for a `FileProvider`, which usually is being supposed to be exported (exposed).

There's a blacklist for the Jetifier (in `gradle.properties`), in case it cannot be disabled:

```
android.jetifier.blacklist=android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS
```

And there's also an `android.jetifier.ignorelist` ...not sure what the actual difference is. This is only a guess, as I cannot reproduce the issue, but it still seems to be a quite likely guess.